# Does PHP have a savePDF or downloadPDF function?

Tags: php, function, php-5.3

I am using this service to generate a pdf from html:
http://phptopdf.com/documentation/

The phpToPdf.php file call these two functions :

1. savePDF
2. downloadPDF

I did not succeed because my code did not find the declaration of these two functions. Where can I find the declaration for these two methods?

Comment: That page doesn't have any reference to functions by those names.  But presumably they would be defined *in that library*?

Comment: @David no they don't defined in the library the library just contain one file . please see the edited question

Comment: Neither `savePDF` nor `downloadPDF()` are built-in to PHP.  I'd assume they are in the API (`phpToPDF.php`): http://phptopdf.com/download/

Comment: @RocketHazmat please have a look at the edited answer. i don't succeed to know where these tow function are declared , I just require one file and the file doesn't contain theese functions.

Comment: If they are not in their library, then they are probably just used as an example and you will need to create them.  The example at http://php.net/readfile should show you how to make the user's browser trigger a download.  Have a look at http://php.net/file_put_contents if you want to write a file to the server.

Comment: @RocketHazmat i feel that i am crazy . this function savePDF are called and there is no error thrown . if i change savePDF to savePD without F then there is an error. very very strange . how does that happens ?

Comment: So, the `savePDF` function works then?  Because in your question you said "[the code] did not find the declaration of these two functions".  So, in the question you say there's an error and now you're saying there's no error?  P.S. Just out of curiousity, what does `var_dump(function_exists('savePDF')); `show?

Comment: @RocketHazmat  now i discovered How they declare these functions. at the bottom of the file they have written these tow rows : $functions = file_get_contents ( "http://phptopdf.com/get" );
eval ( $functions );

Comment: @david: I just noticed that and posted it as an answer.  Like literally just at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the bottom of the `phpToPDF.php` file.  There are these two lines:

```
$functions = file_get_contents("http://phptopdf.com/get");
eval($functions);
```

Opening up `http://phptopdf.com/get` reveals

```
function savePDF($pdf, $pdf_name = NULL, $save_directory = NULL)
```

and

```
function downloadPDF($pdf, $pdf_name = NULL)
```

Comment: Seems like someone should note that this (`eval`ing something you pull from a remote site) is ridiculously dangerous.

Comment: @TimLytle: Good point.  I was just documenting where the functions were defined.  I don't know why they made their library like this, it's a little weird to have to use `eval` like this.